# Change accented characters to lower case using Perl

Tags: perl

I have set of accented characters like this

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

I want to convert upper case accented characters to lower case. I used the `lc` operator, but I can't get the expected output.

For example, I want to convert `Â` to `â`.

If I take an XML entity like `&#x00C2`, if I converted it to lower case it should become `&#x00E2`

Comment: You may need to [define your own mapping](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.0/perlunicode.html).

Comment: They aren't special characters, they are accentuated characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Encode qw(encode decode);

my $enc = 'utf-8'; # This script is stored as UTF-8
my $str = "Ä\n";

# Byte strings:
print lc $str; # prints 'Ä', lc didn't have any effect

# text strings::
my $text_str = decode($enc, $str);
$text_str = lc $text_str;
print encode($enc, $text_str); # prints 'ä', lc worked as expected
```

Try it this may work.

Comment: Thanks @user3916803 i got the Result

Comment: This didn't work under my system - Solaris 10, Perl 5.12.3... output was 
Ä
ï¿½

Answer (score 2):

try using

```
use locale;
print lc("\xE2");
```

and read
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/lc.html

Answer (score 2):

```
 use locale;    
 my $low=lc(\xC2);
 my $up=uc(\xE2);
```

try it this might help you.